# every individual and interaction effects of the following predictors in R

Tags: r, effects, interaction

How do I get every individual and  interaction effects of the following predictors

```
regres <- ~  Rate + Weed + Monocot
```

I would like to include all main effects individually up to a 5 way interaction effect and every possible combination of lower order.

Many thanks!

Comment: How is this question different from [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62485668/how-to-get-every-combination-of-predictors-including-every-interaction-in-r/)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming linear regression the command would be

```r
regres <- lm(outcome ~ Rate * Weed * Monocot)
```

the * versus + is the key

Comment: I'm not sure who downvoted this, but it is a correct answer. When one uses `*` instead of `+` in a formula with `lm()`, the function generates all of the main and lower order interaction effects for the independent variables, as well as the highest order interaction effect. For example, `summary(lm(mpg ~ am * cyl * carb,data = mtcars))` produces a total of 7 effects.  Upvoted.

Comment: LOL thanks I think whoever was just being snarky because it wasn't a very great question, but tbh it was faster to answer than complain about the question.  I debated putting in data = mydata but technically even that isn't necessary if the right variables are in the environment.